# removing array field and value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

i have the following array when i `dd($test)` :

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#81
   +"1": "1"
   +"2": "2"
  }
]
```

and i want to remove the second field and value so the output will be

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#81
   +"1": "1"
  }
]
```

ive been trying to use `array_splice` and `unset` but it doesnt get what i want to remove the field and value, am i doing something wrong? how do i make it happen? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code for what you have tried to do? Show us how you used `array_splice` and `unset`

Comment: @PinballWizard if you do a var_dump($test) what you got as ouput?

Comment: @headmax `dd($test)` is `die(var_dump($test))`; laravel function. See first section of the question above.

Comment: The closest I get to reproduce your dump is by putting an array with your key/value pairs through json_encode. If I'm correct you would need to json_decode your variable to use `unset`

Comment: I've reproduced the array using `$test = [(object)["1" => "1", "2" => "2"]];`, and then using `unset($test[0]->{"1"});` doesn't produce an error, but also doesn't unset the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why unset is not working for you, but this code

```
<?php

$var = [
    0 => [
           "1" => "1",
           "2" => "2",
        ]
    ];

var_dump($var);

unset($var[0]["2"]);

var_dump($var);
```

Will produce this output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1" /// leaving only the one you needed
  }
}
```

You can check it here: https://3v4l.org/37X5s

Comment: Doesn't `array:1 [ 0 => {#81 (...) ];` suggest that `$var[0]` is an `object` and not an `array`?

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 approaches I've found to recreate this, and only one has worked when using `unset`.

Approach 1 - Using `(object)[];`

```
$test = [
  (object)[
    "1" => "1",
    "2" => "2"
];
```

Approach 2 - Using `stdClass()`:

```
$array = new stdClass();

$array->{"1"} = "1";
$array->{"2"} = "2";

$test = [
  $array
];
```

At this point, I try to `unset()` the 2nd key of the first entry in `$test`:

```
unset($test[0]->{"2"});

dd($test);
```

The output of `dd($test);` following this `unset()` is:

```
// Approach 1
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#407 ▼
    +"1": "1"
    +"2": "2"
  }
]

// Approach 2
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#407 ▼
    +"2": "2"
  }
]
```

It seems that using `unset()` works as expected when using `stdClass()`, but if you're casting an `array` as an `object` like I tried in Approach 1, `unset()` will look to work but not actually do anything.

The only way I could get Approach 1 to work is like so:

```
foreach($test AS $tKey => $array){
  $array = (array)$array;
  foreach($array AS $aKey => $value){
    if($key == 2){
      unset($array[$aKey]);
    }
  }
  $test[$tKey] = (object)$array;
}
```

Which works, but seems inefficient as I'm casing the casted array to an `array` then back to an `object`. Hopefully this gives you some insight into the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

i'm guessing the code you printed out here wasn't properly formatted but anyways, to remove and item key and value from an associative array on php, you use the php `unset($var)` function.
Take for instance
`$data = array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2");`
when i call `unset($data["key2"]);`
`$data` now becomes contains only key 1 and value 1.